# Ho do i multiply range slider value with pst attribute then also calculate with other field and then show the result?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Here is my code...

```
<div id="estimate">
<div class="form-group">
  <div class="range-slider">
  <input class="range-slider__range form-control prc e-range" type="range" value="100" min="0" max="500" pst="3">
  <span class="range-slider__value">0</span>
</div>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
  <div class="range-slider">
  <input class="range-slider__range form-control prc e-range" type="range" value="100" min="0" max="500" pst="5">
  <span class="range-slider__value">0</span>
</div>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
    <input type="number" class="form-control prc" value="{{vl}}"/>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
    <input type="number" class="form-control prc" value="5"/>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
  <input type="checkbox" value="10" class="form-control prc">
</div>
<p id="result"></p>
</div>
<script>
estimate();

$('.form-group').on('change','.prc',estimate);

function estimate(){
  let totalSum = 0;
  $('.form-group .prc').each(function(){
    if(this.type=="checkbox" && !this.checked) return
    let inputVal = $(this).val();
    if($.isNumeric(inputVal)){
        totalSum += parseFloat(inputVal);
    }
  });
  
  $('#result').html(totalSum);
}

var rangeSlider = function(){
  var slider = $('.range-slider'),
      range = $('.range-slider__range'),
      value = $('.range-slider__value');
    
  slider.each(function(){

    value.each(function(){
      var value = $(this).prev().attr('value');
      $(this).html(value);
    });

    range.on('input', function(){
      $(this).next(value).html(this.value);
    });
  });
};

rangeSlider();
</script>
```

Here I wants the range slider only multiply value with pst attribute then calculate with other fields and then its show the result..
here can't use any specific id for each item... only can call by any specific class with same type input field like range. and each range vlue should multiply with each pst value then calcualte with other fields

Comment: Not sure what you mean by `pst` attribute. Do you mean `prc`?

Comment: I just wants a aatribute that can multiply with value....

Comment: You would use `.attr()`. Where would you want to get this calculation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider the following example.

```js
estimate();

$('.form-group').on('change', '.prc', estimate);

function estimate() {
  var totalSum = 0,
    add, v, m;
  $('.form-group .prc').each(function(i, el) {
    if ($(el).is(":checkbox") && !$(el).is(":checked")) {
      add = 0;
    } else if ($(el).hasClass("e-range")) {
      v = parseInt($(el).val());
      m = parseInt($(el).attr("pst"));
      add = (v * m);
    } else {
      add = parseFloat($(el).val());
    }
    totalSum += add;
  });

  $('#result').html(totalSum);
}

function rangeSlider() {
  var slider = $('.range-slider'),
    range = $('.range-slider__range'),
    value = $('.range-slider__value');

  slider.each(function() {

    value.each(function() {
      var value = $(this).prev().attr('value');
      $(this).html(value);
    });

    range.on('input', function() {
      $(this).next(value).html(this.value);
    });
  });
};

rangeSlider();
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0-beta1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-giJF6kkoqNQ00vy+HMDP7azOuL0xtbfIcaT9wjKHr8RbDVddVHyTfAAsrekwKmP1" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0-beta1/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-ygbV9kiqUc6oa4msXn9868pTtWMgiQaeYH7/t7LECLbyPA2x65Kgf80OJFdroafW" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<div id="estimate">
  <div class="form-group">
    <div class="range-slider">
      <input class="range-slider__range form-control prc e-range" type="range" value="100" min="0" max="500" pst="3">
      <span class="range-slider__value">0</span>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <div class="range-slider">
      <input class="range-slider__range form-control prc e-range" type="range" value="100" min="0" max="500" pst="5">
      <span class="range-slider__value">0</span>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <input type="number" class="form-control prc" value="0" />
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <input type="number" class="form-control prc" value="5" />
  </div>
  <div class="form-group form-check">
    <input type="checkbox" value="10" class="form-check-input form-control prc"> <label class="form-check-label">10</label>
  </div>
  <p id="result"></p>
</div>
```

If you need to get the attribute of an element, use `.attr()`.

See more:

- https://api.jquery.com/attr/

Comment: only problem in this code is checkbox.. if i un checked then it calcualting which should be like if i checked then it should add that value

Comment: but its solved after change the first condiion to ( this.type=="checkbox" && !this.checked )